# How to set ReFrames in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I tried to set the ReFrames to 3 using the above command, but the output shown by MediaInfo is always ReFrames = 4 frames.

I also tried `"-x264opts ref=3"`, but still the ReFrames is always 4.
How to set this using the right ffmpeg option?

`ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.000 -t 00:00:18.000 -i /input -ss 00:00:18.001 -t 00:00:35.000 -i /media/C4_TCODEIN01/dmt-201/IN_C1XE7MCO-EXCELLENCECREME_6036330 -filter_complex "[0:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part1crop]; [1:v:0]crop=out_h=576:y=32,yadif=1:-1:0[part2crop];[part1crop][0:a:0] [part2crop][1:a:0]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[vconcat][aconcat]" -map '[vconcat]' -codec:v libx264 -profile:v High -level 4.1 -coder 1 -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_track_timescale 25 -r 25 -s:v 1920x1080 -aspect 16:9 -x264-params "cabac=1:no-deblock=0:ref=3:weightp=2:chroma_qp_offset=0:keyint=50:keyint_min=5:bframes=3:b_pyramid=2:b-adapt=2:subme=7:b_bias=0:direct=1:weightb=1:open_gop=0:scenecut=40:nal-hrd=vbr:bitrate=15000:vbv_maxrate=22500:vbv-bufsize=30000:threads=7:lookahead_threads=1" -map '[aconcat]' -codec:a libfdk_aac -ac 2 -b:a 192K -write_tmcd off /media/OUT_24.mp4`

Media Info:

```
Format                                   : MPEG-4
Format profile                           : Base Media
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size                                : 54.9 MiB
Duration                                 : 35 s 80 ms
Overall bit rate mode                    : Variable
Overall bit rate                         : 13.1 Mb/s
Writing application                      : Lavf57.56.101

Video
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : AVC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                           : High@L4.1
Format settings                          : CABAC / 4 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC                   : Yes
Format settings, Reference frames        : 4 frames
Codec ID                                 : avc1
Codec ID/Info                            : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                                 : 35 s 80 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Variable
Bit rate                                 : 12.9 Mb/s
Nominal bit rate                         : 15.0 Mb/s
Maximum bit rate                         : 22.5 Mb/s
Width                                    : 1 920 pixels
Height                                   : 1 080 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 16:9
Frame rate mode                          : Constant
Frame rate                               : 25.000 FPS
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 0.250
Stream size                              : 54.1 MiB (98%)
Writing library                          : x264 core 148
Encoding settings                        : cabac=1 / ref=3 / deblock=1:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=7 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=3 / b_pyramid=2 / b_adapt=2 / b_bias=0 / direct=1 / weightb=1 / open_gop=0 / weightp=2 / keyint=50 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=40 / rc=abr / mbtree=1 / bitrate=15000 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / vbv_maxrate=22500 / vbv_bufsize=30000 / nal_hrd=vbr / filler=0 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Codec configuration box                  : avcC

Audio
ID                                       : 2
Format                                   : AAC LC
Format/Info                              : Advanced Audio Codec Low Complexity
Codec ID                                 : mp4a-40-2
Duration                                 : 35 s 42 ms
Duration_LastFrame                       : -9 ms
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 192 kb/s
Channel(s)                               : 2 channels
Channel layout                           : L R
Sampling rate                            : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate                               : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Stream size                              : 822 KiB (1%)
Default                                  : Yes
Alternate group                          : 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `b_pyramid` to 1. If set to 2, x264 will force minimum refs to 4.